# Writing utf-8 string inside my python files

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

This line in my .py file is giving me a: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-13: unsupported Unicode code range"

```
if line.startswith(u"Fußnote"):
```

The file is saved in utf-8 and has the encoding at the top:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

I've got a lot of other py files with utf-8 encoded chinese text in them in the comments and in arrays for example:  arr = [u"chinese text",] so I'm wondering why this case in particular doesn't work for me.

Comment: How do you know for sure it's really utf-8. Can you look at the appropriate output of `od -t c` on the file (if Unix)?

Comment: There are also `hexdump -C` on most GNU/Linux distros and `hd(1)` on FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanks guys for the great answers, I moved and am away from my windows box I was working on. I was tearing my hair out over this, but I think I finally understand unicode. When I get back to it I'll accept an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's examine that error message very closely:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-13: unsupported Unicode code range"

Note carefully that it says "bytes in position 8-13" -- that's a **6-byte UTF-8 sequence**. That might have been valid in the dark ages, but *since Unicode was frozen at 21 bits, the maximum is FOUR bytes*. UTF-8 validations and error reporting [were tightened up recently](http://bugs.python.org/issue8271); as a matter of interest, exactly what version of Python are you running?

With 2.7.1 and 2.6.6 at least, that error becomes the more useful "... can't decode byte XXXX in position 8: invalid start byte" where XXXX can be only be 0xfc or 0xfd if the old message suggested a 6-byte sequence. In ISO-8859-1 or cp1252, 0xfc represents U+00FC LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS (aka u-umlaut, a likely suspect); 0xfd represents U+00FD LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE (less likely).

The problem is NOT with the `if line.startswith(u"Fußnote"):` statement in your source file. You would have got a message at COMPILE time if it wasn't proper UTF-8, and the message would have started with "SyntaxError", not "UnicodeDecodeError". In any case the UTF-8 encoding of that string is only 8 bytes long, not 14.

The problem is (as @Mark Tolonen has pointed out) in whatever "line" is referring to. It can only be a str object.

To get further you need to answer Mark's questions (1) result of `print repr(line)` (2) `site.py` change.

At this stage it's a good idea to clear the air about mixing `str` and `unicode` objects (in many operations, not just `a.startswith(b)`).

*Unless the operation is defined to produce a `str` object, it will NOT coerce the `unicode` object to `str`.* This is not the case with `a.startswith(b)`.It will attempt to decode the `str` object using the default (usually 'ascii') encoding.

Examples:

```
>>> "\xff".startswith(u"\xab")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> u"\xff".startswith("\xab")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Furthermore, *it is NOT correct to say "Mix and you get UnicodeDecodeError".* It is quite possible that the `str` object is validly encoded in the default encoding (usually 'ascii') -- no exception is raised.

Examples:

```
>>> "abc".startswith(u"\xff")
False
>>> u"\xff".startswith("abc")
False
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the updating python mention, and the full explanation.

Comment: Hi Mark ... thanks for the upvote and answer acceptance. Please note that we still don't know what caused the problem; it would be helpful to future readers if you were to answer @MarkTolonen's 2 questions (edit your question, please, don't do it in a comment).

Answer (score 6):

I can reproduce the UnicodeDecodeError with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -- coding: utf-8 --

line='Fußnoteno'
if line.startswith(u"Fußnote"):
    print('Hi')
```

Note that `line` is a string object, but `u"Fußnote"` is a unicode object.
Since `line` is a string object, the unicode object is being converted to a string object in the call to `startswith`. In Python2, the default is to try to decode using the ascii codec. 
Since `u"ß"` can't be decoded with the ascii codec, a UnicodeDecodeError is raised.

The error can be avoided if you first make `line` a unicode object:

```
line='Fußnoteno'.decode('utf-8')
if line.startswith(u"Fußnote"):
    print('Hi')
```

or if you first make `u"Fußnote"` a string object:

```
line='Fußnoteno'
if line.startswith(u"Fußnote".encode('utf-8')):
    print('Hi')
```

Comment: -1 for 2 reasons (1) you have NOT reproduced that (unusual) error message, you would have got the plain variety (2) the unicode object is **NOT** being converted to a string [you mean `str`] object in the call to startswith. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates *line* is not a Unicode string.  In `X.startswith(Y)` both X and Y must be Unicode or byte string.  Mix and you get UnicodeDecodeError.  `print repr(line)` to inspect it.  Also have you altered `site.py` to change the default encoding from 'ascii' to 'utf8'?  Normally it is the 'ascii' codec that is the default for Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, it's unclear if the problem is the code or the data file the code is reading.

When you open the file, are you doing:

```
file = open("essay.txt")
```

or:

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open("essay.txt", encoding="utf-8")
```

What does:

```
print file.encoding
```

say if you add it just below the `open` line?

Both of these ways work for me:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

file = open("essay.txt")

print file.encoding

for line in file:
    uline = line.decode("utf-8")
    print type(uline)
    if uline.startswith(u"Fußnote"):
        print "Footnote"
    else:
        print "Other"
```

and this way:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import codecs
file = codecs.open("essay.txt", encoding="utf-8")

print file.encoding

for line in file:
    print type(line)
    if line.startswith(u"Fußnote"):
        print "Footnote"
    else:
        print "Other"
```

In the first one, I am letting Python default to opening the file as a byte stream, then converting each line from a byte stream to a Unicode string using `uline = line.decode("utf-8")`.

In the second one, I am opening the file as a UTF-8 encoded file, so Python returns Unicode strings when I iterate over the file.

---

**EDIT**

Here's a trivial way you could use to find out if the file contained any non-utf8 data.

```
import codecs
file = open("baduni.txt")
try:
    for char in codecs.iterdecode(file, "utf-8"):
        print char
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print "error:", e
```

And an example of it in use:

```
$ echo 'ABC\0200\0101DEF' > baduni.txt
$ od -c baduni.txt
0000000   A   B   C 200   A   D   E   F  \n
0000011
$ python testuni.py
error: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

In the example, the 4th byte (position 3, counting from 0) is `200` octal/`0x80` hexadecimal.
[The Wikipedia UTF-8 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) shows that that would only be valid as the second byte of a two-byte sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is saved in some other encoding, and *not* UTF-8. Figure out what encoding the file is in (possibly CP1252 or so), and declare that instead.