# Python Unicode Decode Error for Byte not in file

Tags: python, c++, unicode

I am reading a large file in python line by line with `readline()`. After reaching close to 672,280 lines I get an error:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 228:
 invalid start byte.
```

However, I have searched the file using `grep` for a byte `0xfd` and it returned none. I also wrote `c++` code to go through the file and look for a byte `0xfd` and still got nothing. So I have no idea what is going on here. Is it an error because the file is too big?

I just don't see how a decoding error can happen for a byte not in a file.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing utf-8 string inside my python files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812186/writing-utf-8-string-inside-my-python-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try out to open file with ISO encoding.

```
open('myfile.txt', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```